# Hidden Markov Model how to generate probabilities

Tags: python, machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, markov

I have a lot of data from pulse\heart rate measurements, so the data is in long integer lists, and I have 8 states (although the data can range to much more than 1 to 8- it can be 50 to 140).
I want an algorithm which can take the measurements data and through unsupervised learning to give me the probability to move from one state to another.
So I don't know the transition-matrix, and I don't know on the measurement data to allocate the different states.
all I have is 8 states, vectors with the heart-rate measurements, and I need to get the probabilities to move from one state to all others.
I'm not sure how can I use HMM to do it, or is it a way to do it at all.

Comment: could you be more specific?
an example will be helpful

Comment: So you have 8 known states (obversable?) and the hidden states are 50-140? Or is it the other way around?

Comment: The HMM's algo's I found so far (for python) calculated the probability to get a specific sequence, but what I need is to calculate the prob's to go from one state to another when all of the sequences are given

Comment: I have 8 states (not observabale- 8 emotions) which are the hidden states, and data of heart-rate, which I want to say that the data (the heart-rate sequence) has 8 hidden states in it, as you can understand which emotion the person having by knowing his heart-rate. so I want to know based on the data I had collected what are the probs to move from one hidden state to another

Answer (score 0):

almost any time series data could be modeled by HMM. transition matrix should be estimated from the data using well known Baum-Welch algorithm.Simple tutorial from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baum%E2%80%93Welch_algorithm) should give u a hints.

Comment: That's not completely true, continuous timeseries (and e.g. heartbeats/time unit is continous) are not easy to model with HMM (as they would result in an infinite state space), you would have to use something like a continuous density hidden Markov model. Also timeseries with a finite large state space become intractable to compute quite soon (oftentimes approximations such as particle filters are used then).

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of [TICC](https://web.stanford.edu/~hallac/TICC.pdf)?

It's an Inverse Covariance-Based Clustering of
Multivariate Time Series Data. This algorithm can help you use heart rate measurements (and many other data ) and use an unsupervised method to identify different states. This algorithm is really good because you can specify two critical tuning parameters:

1. `number_of_clusters`: The number of expected states in your data. In this case, you have 8 observed states. That will make the traning of the algorithm much more accurate.
2. `beta`: The switch penalty. You can control how easy/difficult for the algorithm to switch from one state to another. This could be straight forward if you have a good knowledge of your problem or, if not, be subject to try and error.

I recommend having a look at [TICC implementation in Python.](https://github.com/davidhallac/TICC)

Here's a quick example:

```
fname = "bar_shaul_data.txt"
ticc = TICC(window_size=1, number_of_clusters=8, lambda_parameter=11e-2, beta=600, maxIters=100, threshold=2e-5,
            write_out_file=False, prefix_string="output_folder/", num_proc=1)
(cluster_assignment, cluster_MRFs) = ticc.fit(input_file=fname)

print(cluster_assignment)
np.savetxt('Results.txt', cluster_assignment, fmt='%d', delimiter=',')
```

More docs are available on [README](https://github.com/davidhallac/TICC/blob/master/README.md).

Disclaimer: I'm a contributor to the library.